# On multiplying by diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

Given two matrices $A,B\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ supposing there exists a diagonal matrix $D\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ such $$AD=DB$$ does that mean $A,B$ are diagonals and hence equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Take $D$ to be the zero matrix and let $A,B$ be non-equal matrices.

A non trivial example is to take $A,B$ to be diagonal with different entries in some coordinates and $D$ to be diagonal with zeros in the coordinates where $A,B$ differ.

In fact, even if $A,B$ are the same matrix, its not necessarily the case that $AD=DA$; a diagonal matrix $D=diag(d_1,d_2,\ldots)$ commutes with $A=[a_{ij}]$ if and only if $a_{ij}=0$ whenever $d_i \neq d_j$.

Comment: I updated post but i can very well accept this and make a new post?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578851/on-multiplying-symmetric-matrices-by-diagonal-matrices-with-roots-of-unity

Comment: Even with the edited question, you use the last fact to show the answer is still no. You can use the following matlab code to see this: A=randn(2); A=A+A'; D=diag(1,-1); A*D-D*A and you'll see A*D-D*A will be non-zero almost always.

Comment: could you post your opinion in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578851/on-multiplying-symmetric-matrices-by-diagonal-matrices-with-roots-of-unity?

Comment: problem is about if they are equal what happens

Answer (score 2):

This is a counterexample:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&2\\
0&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&2\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&2\\
0&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578851/on-multiplying-symmetric-matrices-by-diagonal-matrices-with-roots-of-unity

Answer (score 2):

No.  Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\1&1 \end {pmatrix},D=\begin{pmatrix} 2&0\\0&1 \end {pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1/2\\2&1 \end {pmatrix}$

Comment: I updated post but i can very well accept this and make a new post?

Comment: I think you should leave the original because all the answers refer to it.  Then make a new post with the new question, but you might show that you have tried something.

Comment: could you try this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578851/on-multiplying-symmetric-matrices-by-diagonal-matrices-with-roots-of-unity?